# ERROR @wdio/local-runner: Failed launching test session: Error: Couldn't find page handle at DevToolsDriver.getPageHandle

Tags: javascript, node.js, automation, ui-automation, webdriver-io

I am new to webdriverIO, while trying to run using cucumber framework, even though the execution is happening, I see the steps are retried as if there was a failure
ERROR @wdio/local-runner: Failed launching test session: Error: Couldn't find page handle
at DevToolsDriver.getPageHandle (D:\webdriverio\test2\node_modules\devtools\build\devtoolsdriver.js:143:19) can anyone help how to resolve this?

//----------- Cucumber Config Details -------------//

```
const path = require("path");

exports.config = {
  runner: "local",

  headless: false,

  specs: ["./test.feature"],

  maxInstances: 1,

  maxInstancesPerCapability: 10,

  capabilities: [
    {


     browserName: "chrome",
    },
  ],

  logLevel: "trace",

  outputDir: "./",

  bail: 0,

  waitforTimeout: 1000,

  framework: "cucumber",
  specFileRetries: 1,

  specFileRetriesDelay: 0,

  specFileRetriesDeferred: false,

  cucumberOpts: {
    require: [path.join(__dirname, "step-definitions", "my-steps.js")],
    backtrace: true,
    compiler: [],
    dryRun: false,
    failFast: false,
    format: ["pretty"],
    snippets: true,
    source: true,
    profile: [],
    strict: false,
    tagExpression: "",
    timeout: 20000,
    ignoreUndefinedDefinitions: false,
    scenarioLevelReporter: false,
  },
};
```

//---------- Step definition-------------//

```
const {Given} = require("@cucumber/cucumber");

Given("I navigate to webdriverIo", async function () {

  await browser.url("https://duckduckgo.com");

  const inputElem = await browser.$("#search_form_input_homepage");

  await inputElem.setValue("WebdriverIO");

  const submitBtn = await browser.$("#search_button_homepage");

  await submitBtn.click();

  console.log(await browser.getTitle()); // outputs: "Title is: WebdriverIO (Software) at DuckDuckGo"

  await browser.deleteSession();

});
```

//-------------- wdio.Log ----------------//]

```
 2021-04-18T01:17:24.886Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onPrepare hook

`2021-04-18T01:17:24.893Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onWorkerStart hook

2021-04-18T01:17:24.895Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Start worker 0-0 with arg: .\testRunner.js

2021-04-18T01:17:39.068Z DEBUG @wdio/local-runner: Runner 0-0 finished with exit code 1

2021-04-18T01:17:39.073Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onWorkerStart hook

2021-04-18T01:17:39.074Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Start worker 0-0 with arg: .\testRunner.js

2021-04-18T01:17:51.990Z DEBUG @wdio/local-runner: Runner 0-0 finished with exit code 1

2021-04-18T01:17:51.994Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onComplete hook

2021-04-18T01:17:52.033Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Shutting down spawned worker

2021-04-18T01:17:52.289Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Waiting for 0 to shut down gracefully
```

//-------------- wdio-0-0.Log ----------------//

```
2021-04-18T01:17:40.546Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Run worker command: run

2021-04-18T01:17:40.555Z DEBUG @wdio/config:ConfigParser: No compiler found, continue without compiling files

2021-04-18T01:17:40.560Z DEBUG @wdio/local-runner:utils: init remote session

2021-04-18T01:17:41.601Z DEBUG @wdio/local-runner:utils: init remote session

2021-04-18T01:17:41.622Z INFO devtools:puppeteer: Initiate new session using the DevTools protocol

2021-04-18T01:17:41.623Z INFO devtools: Launch Google Chrome with flags: --enable-automation --disable-popup-blocking --disable-extensions --disable-background-networking --disable-background-timer-throttling --disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows --disable-sync --metrics-recording-only --disable-default-apps --mute-audio --no-first-run --no-default-browser-check --disable-hang-monitor --disable-prompt-on-repost --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --password-store=basic --use-mock-keychain --disable-component-extensions-with-background-pages --disable-breakpad --disable-dev-shm-usage --disable-ipc-flooding-protection --disable-renderer-backgrounding --force-fieldtrials=*BackgroundTracing/default/ --enable-features=NetworkService,NetworkServiceInProcess --disable-features=site-per-process,TranslateUI,BlinkGenPropertyTrees --window-position=0,0 --window-size=1200,900

2021-04-18T01:17:42.177Z INFO devtools: Connect Puppeteer with browser on port 54789

2021-04-18T01:17:42.722Z INFO devtools: COMMAND 
navigateTo("https://duckduckgo.com/")

2021-04-18T01:17:46.810Z INFO devtools: RESULT null

2021-04-18T01:17:46.824Z INFO devtools: COMMAND findElement("css selector", "#search_form_input_homepage")

2021-04-18T01:17:46.833Z INFO devtools: RESULT { 'element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf': 'ELEMENT-1' }

2021-04-18T01:17:46.862Z INFO devtools: COMMAND elementClear("ELEMENT-1")

2021-04-18T01:17:46.875Z INFO devtools: RESULT null

2021-04-18T01:17:46.892Z INFO devtools: COMMAND elementSendKeys("ELEMENT-1", "WebdriverIO")

2021-04-18T01:17:47.044Z INFO devtools: RESULT null

2021-04-18T01:17:47.051Z INFO devtools: COMMAND findElement("css selector", "#search_button_homepage")

2021-04-18T01:17:47.055Z INFO devtools: RESULT { 'element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf': 'ELEMENT-2' }

2021-04-18T01:17:47.085Z INFO devtools: COMMAND elementClick("ELEMENT-2")

2021-04-18T01:17:47.438Z INFO devtools: RESULT null

2021-04-18T01:17:51.904Z INFO devtools: COMMAND getTitle()

2021-04-18T01:17:51.907Z INFO devtools: RESULT WebdriverIO at DuckDuckGo

2021-04-18T01:17:51.913Z INFO devtools: COMMAND deleteSession()

2021-04-18T01:17:51.918Z INFO devtools: RESULT null

2021-04-18T01:17:51.935Z ERROR @wdio/local-runner: Failed launching test session: Error: Couldn't find page handle

    at DevToolsDriver.getPageHandle (D:\webdriverio\test2\node_modules\devtools\build\devtoolsdriver.js:143:19)

    at DevToolsDriver.checkPendingNavigations (D:\webdriverio\test2\node_modules\devtools\build\devtoolsdriver.js:152:25)

    at Browser.wrappedCommand (D:\webdriverio\test2\node_modules\devtools\build\devtoolsdriver.js:70:24)

    at Browser.wrapCommandFn (D:\webdriverio\test2\node_modules\@wdio\utils\build\shim.js:78:38)

    at async Runner.endSession (D:\webdriverio\test2\node_modules\@wdio\runner\build\index.js:340:9)

    at async Runner.run (D:\webdriverio\test2\node_modules\@wdio\runner\build\index.js:160:13)
```

Comment: Add some code you are running.

Comment: Were you able to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the exact solution for your issue but adding it here for others, I receieved this error:

> **ERROR @wdio/local-runner: Failed launching test session: TypeError: Cannot set property 'failures' of undefined at WdioMochawesomeReporter. ...**

**Short Answer**: Run only files which have tests in them.

This [github](https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues/6237) issue helped me to fix my "specs" regex in `wdio.conf.js` file.

- specs when error occurred: `"specs: [ './tests/**/*.js' ]"`

  - it was running some utility files also *which did not have any tests in them* and hence test runner failed,
- specs now (fixed version): `"specs: [ './tests/**/*-functional.test.js' ]"`

Also, I received this error only when `mochawesome` reporter added to `wdio.cong.js` file.